# On the minimum distance along an orbit

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, group-actions, spheres, isometry

Let $\Gamma$ be a nontrivial group of isometries of $\mathbb{S}^n$, $n \geq 2$, acting properly discontinuously. For $p \in \mathbb{S}^n$, define

$$r(p) = \min_{g \in \Gamma \setminus\{e\} } d(p, g(p)), $$

that is, $r(p)$ is the minimum distance to $p$ of a point in its orbit. As the sphere is a homogeneous manifold, I expect $r$ to be a constant function, although I couldn't prove it. Any thoughts on it?

Comment: No, it is not a constant function. Hint: Consider $n=1$ and $\Gamma$ generated by a reflection.

Comment: You mean the antipodal map?

Comment: No, I mean a reflection.

Comment: OK, take a group generated by a hyperplane reflection in $R^{n+1}$ where $n$ is your favorite number.

Comment: The isometry cannot have fixed points

Comment: Since when an isometry cannot have fixed points? Do you regard the identity map as an isometry? What's your definition of an isometry then and how are they supposed to form a group?

Comment: To act properly and discontinuously

Comment: OK, what's your defintion of "acting properly and discontinuosuly" (the standard notion by the way "act properly discontinuously"). I think, you wanted to add "freely".

Comment: Doesn't it imply freeness?

Comment: Every point $p$ has a neighbourhood $U$ such that $U \cap gU = \emptyset$ for $g \neq e$.

Comment: No, it does not. The standard notion of a PD action is that for every compact subset $C$ the subset $\{g\in G: gC\cap C\ne \emptyset\}$ is finite.

Comment: Oh, there hasn't been a consensus about the definition. But what I mean by a PD action is what I wrote in the above comment.

Answer (score 2):

Given a group $G$ acting on a metric space $X$ define the *displacement function*  $\delta_g(x):= d(x, g(x))$, $g\in G$. One way the displacement function of $g$ can be constant is if the centralizer $C(g)$ of $g$ in the isometry group of $X$ acts transitively on $X$. The reason is that $\delta_g= \delta_{fgf^{-1}}$. Hence, for $f\in C(g)$,
$$
\delta_g(f(x))= d(gf(x), f(x))= d(f^{-1}g f(x), x)= d(g(x), x)= \delta_{g}(x) 
$$
Therefore, if $C(g)$ acts transtively on $X$, then $\delta_g$ is constant.

Otherwise, $\delta_g$ tends to be nonconstant. For instance, if $g$ is an isometry of the Euclidean space then $\delta_g$  is constant if and only if $g$ is a translation. If $X$ is a hyperbolic space then it's even worse, $\delta_g$ is constant if and only if $g=id$. Now, consider the case when $X=S^{n-1}$ with the standard angular metric $d$.

Lemma. $g\in O(n)$ has constant displacement on $(S^{n-1},d)$ if and only if either $g=\pm id$ (if $n$ is odd) or for any two eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ of $g$ we have $\lambda_1=\lambda_2^{\pm 1}$ (if $n$ is even). (Note that all the eigenvalues $\lambda$ have absolute value $1$, hence $\lambda^{-1}= \bar\lambda$.)

Proof. I will consider the more interesting case of $n=2k$ and leave you to work out the odd-dimensional case. Suppose that $g\in O(n)$ acts on $S^{n-1}$ with constant displacement function.

Let $\lambda^{\pm 1}_1,...,\lambda^{\pm 1}_k$ denote the complex eigenvalues of $g$ (taken with multiplicity). If some $\lambda_j=1$ then $g$ has a fixed point on $S^n$, hence, $\delta_g$ constant implies that $g=id$. Similarly, if some $\lambda_j=-1$, then for its unit eigenvector $v\in {\mathbb R}^n$, we have $d(v, gv)=\pi$, hence,  $d(u, gu)=\pi$ for all $u\in S^{n-1}$, i.e. $g=-id$.

Suppose, therefore, that all eigenvalues of $g$ are non-real.

Let $E_1\oplus ...\oplus E_k={\mathbb R}^{2k}$ be the eigenspace decomposition: Each $E_j$ is 2-dimensional and if we identify it isometrically with the complex plane, then $g$ acts on $E_j$ via multiplication by $\lambda_j$ or $\lambda_j^{-1}$. Next, let's compute the displacements of  the restrictions of $g$ to the circles $E_j\cap S^{n-1}$: For a unit vector $u\in E_j$, we have 
$$
d(u, \lambda_j u)= |arg(\lambda_j)|.
$$
It follows that the arguments of all the eigenvalues of $g$ have the form $\pm \theta$ for some fixed $\theta\in [-\pi, \pi]$. Hence, $\lambda_j=e^{\pm i\theta}$ for $j=1,...,n$.

The converse direction is equally pleasant: Under suitable identification of ${\mathbb R}^{2k}$ with ${\mathbb C}^k$, $g$ acts as a scalar multiplication
$$
u\mapsto e^{i\theta}u, u\in {\mathbb C}^k.  
$$
From this it is easy to see that $g$ acts with the displacemnt $\theta$ on $S^n$. 
You can also observe that the centralizer of such $g$ in $O(n)$ is $U(k)$ and, hence, acts transitively on $S^{n-1}$. qed

Note that the displacement function of $g\in O(n)$ is clearly real-analytic. Hence, if it is constant on a nonempty open subset of $S^{n-1}$ then $\delta_g$ is constant on the entire sphere.

Now, to your question. You have a finite subgroup $G<O(n)$ acting freely on $S^{n-1}$ and define the function 
$$
r(p)= \min_{g\in G- e} \delta_g(p). 
$$
This function is piecewise-analytic on $S^{n-1}$: there exists a nowehere dense subset $E\subset S^{-1}$, such that for every component $U$ of $S^{n-1} -E$, there exists $g=g_U\in G$ such that
$$
r|_U= \delta_g|_U. 
$$
Now, if the function $r$ were constant on $S^{n-1}$, we would have that for each $g_U$, $\delta_{g_U}$ is constant. So, what's left is to find a finite subgroup $G< O(n)$ acting freely on $S^{n-1}$ such that the only element $g\in G$   with constant $\delta_g$ is the identity. In view of the lemma, it suffices to consider the case of even $n$ and look for $G$ such that every $g\in G-\{e\}$ has at least two eigenvalues with distinct (absolute values of) their arguments.

For instance: Consider a finite group $G$ generated by the orthogonal transformation
$$
g: (z,w) \mapsto (e^{2\pi i/p}z,  (e^{4\pi i/p}w), 
$$
where $(z,w)\in {\mathbb C}^2$, where $p>3$ is prime. For instance, $p= 7$, which I like more than $p=5$ somehow.

Comment: This is $L(7,2)$, right?

Comment: Why it is not constant?

Comment: @EduardoLonga: That's an exercise. Compare a point on the $z$-axis with a point slightly off the $z$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add more explanation on Moishe Cohen's example :

i) Consider a curve $c(t):=(e^{2\pi t}z,0)$ in $S^3$. If
$U_\varepsilon(c)$ is a tubular neighborhood, then there is a
diffeomorphism $$ f :  S^1\times B_\varepsilon(0) \rightarrow
U_\varepsilon(c)$$ s.t. (1) $B_\varepsilon(0)$ is flat
$\varepsilon$-ball

(2) $B_\varepsilon (0)$ is identified to
$\varepsilon$-ball in $c'(t)^\perp$

(3) $ f(t,x)=\exp_{c(t)}\ x $ and

(4) If $U_\varepsilon (c)$ has an free isometric action
$g(z,w)=(e^\frac{2\pi i}{p} z,e^\frac{2\pi i l}{p}
w)$, then $f$ preserves the free isometric action.

ii) If we fix $x_0\in c'(0)^\perp,\ |x_0|=\varepsilon$,
then define $r_t:=\exp_{c(t)} \ x_t$ where $x_t$ is a parallel
transport of $x_0$ along $c(t)$. Since $S^3$ is not flat manifold,
so $x_0\neq x_\delta$ for small $\delta\neq 0$.

iii) Note that $d(r_\delta,r_0)<2\pi\delta$.

iv) Here all numbers in sequence are natural number. Then
there are $p_i,\ u_i$ s.t. $p_i,\ u_i\rightarrow \infty$, $0<
u_i<p_i$, $p_i$ is a prime and
$\frac{2\pi u_i}{p_i}\rightarrow 2\pi \delta $.

If angle between $x_0$ and $x_\delta$ is $\theta$, where $\theta$ is
small, then there is a sequence $p_i,\ r_i$ s.t. $0<r_i<p_i$ and
$\frac{2\pi r_i}{p_i}\rightarrow\theta$.

In further there are $l_i,\ m_i$ .t. $l_i,\ m_i\rightarrow \infty$
and $\delta l_i- m_i \rightarrow \frac{\theta }{2\pi}$.

Hence if $g^{u_k}\cdot (z,w)= (\frac{2\pi u_ki}{p_k} z, \frac{2\pi
u_kl_k i}{p_k} w)$, then $d(g^{u_k} \cdot r_0, r_\delta)\rightarrow
0$.